# Proxying requests with Connection: Keep-Alive

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

We have an app which sits behind an Apache instance using mod_proxy to pass requests to the correct app server.

Our app correctly returns a `Connection: Keep-Alive` when queried directly, but mod_proxy is scrubbing the header.

I did some reading and a few suggested that the client needs to set a `Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive` to the the proxy about this, but that didn't work either.

Is it possible to have persistent connection proxied by apache?

Comment: Is the KeepAlive parameter in apache on or off?

Comment: It is off at the moment, however my reading suggests that the KeepAlive parameter refers to sending TCP keepalives to the backend, and seems somewhat seperate to the HTTP 1.1 Keep-Alive.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you say apache has KeepAlive off, I'm guessing its closing the connection.  Try turning it on per [KeepAlive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#keepalive)

Comment: I tried it after I read your comment. Didn't fix the issue. Some weird gzip flag did in the end, and then to add insult to injury the top level problem turned out not to be anything to do with apache.